# Merging two tables on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two different tables, one with new data and one with old, I need to copy the data from the new one into the old, first I need to insert all the ones that are new all together, then I need to find what ones have been updated and update them, then I need to delete all the ones that aren't in the table, the first one is easy, I just used `MERGE INTO x A USING(select z from c) B ON A.z = B.z WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT....`

But when it comes to the update I started to write it, I wrote the merge when it doesn't match, but I need the primary key to match so I know thats the one to update, how am I meant to do that?

The last delete should be fine, I will just create a table with all the keys that aren't in the new one any more and then delete them

The problem is with the update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will give you some idea

```
--Synchronize source data with target
MERGE INTO dbo.tbl_Target AS t
    USING dbo.tbl_Source AS s    
        ON t.id = s.id
    WHEN MATCHED AND (t.name != s.name OR t.qty!= s.qty) THEN
        --Row exists and data is different
        UPDATE SET t.name = s.name, t.qty = s.qty
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
        --Row exists in source but not in target
        INSERT VALUES (s.id, s.name, s.qty) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        --Row exists in target but not in source
        DELETE OUTPUT$action, inserted.id, deleted.id
```

Comment: I actually had figured that out after reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx again, thanks :)